# Problemas ao inserir novo registro ao Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Notei um problema com o código, quando tento inserir um novo registro em uma entidade, perco todos os antigos registros e somente o novo fica guardado.

Código usado:

```
NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self managedObjectContext];

NSManagedObjectContext * novoObjeto = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName: entidadeBebidas inManagedObjectContext: context];

[novoObjeto setValue: novoValor forKey: @ "id"];

NSError * error = nil;

if (![context save: & error]) {
    //[self alertaErroCadastro];
    //NSLog(@"Erro ao salvar no banco local");
}
```

Antes da inserção:

```
| id |
12542
12542
25412
21452
```

Depois da inserção do novo registro:

```
| id |
998698
```

Os registros anteriores são perdidos.

Comment: Reproduzi aqui e a inserção funcionou sem problemas, você poderia postar mais detalhes?

Comment: Bom eu estou usando esse código dentro de um looping `for`

Comment: Tentou trocar o tipo de novoObjeto para `NSManagedObject`?

Comment: Obrigado pela sugestao... Vou testar agora e ja digo se funcionou...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o erro, existia um `if` dentro do corpo do método que decidia se fosse incremento e decremento de registro.

O Problema, primeiro bloco do `if` modificava algumas variáveis que tornava a condição `True` para entrar no segundo `if` e removia os valores de maneira invertida.

Concertei o código e isolei as funções em métodos distintos. E removi a referencia para as mesmas variáveis.